# Jquery Validation Central Message Many Errors

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that is being valdated with the Jquery Validation Plugin.
I have managed to get a centeral message "Please Recheck the form", and to have the input focus on the first error. To get this, I had to override the default message of each of the errors.
I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how I can have it display the error message associated with the first error input instead of a general error message. Here is the code:

```
$("#Help-A-Noobie-Form" ).validate({

 invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {      
     $(this).find(":input.error:first").focus();
     var message = 'Please Recheck The Form' ;
    $("#Help-A-Noobie-Form #Message p").addClass('red').html(message);        
   },

showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
```

this.defaultShowErrors();
       },

rules: {
          required:true,
          email: {email:true},
          phone: {digits:true}
           },

messages: { 
             email: "",
             phone: "",
             lastname: "",
             firstname: "",
              required:""
                      }
})

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#Help-A-Noobie-Form" ).validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        if (errorList.length > 0) {
            jQuery('.errors').html('<div id="error" class="erreur">' + errorList[0].message + '</div>');
        }
    }, 
    rules: {
        email: { email:true },
        phone: { digits:true }
    },  

    messages: { 
        email: { email: 'please enter a valid email' },
        phone: { digits: 'please enter a valid phone' }
    }
});
```